# JavaScript - Element.closest does not get styled

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been browsing the MDN documentation on JavaScript and came across the `Element.closest` property. This is still only an experimental property, but it's important to understand how to use it.

Here's what the spec says

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

```js
var par = document.getElementById('my-id');

par.closest("h2").style.background = "yellow";
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="third">    
      <p id="my-id">This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use the latest version of Google Chrome. According to the compatibility chart, this should work on Google Chrome 41+

I can't find any reason why this doesn't work.

Any theories?

Comment: This might help to understand the DOM terminology: http://felix-kling.de/images/DOM_relationship.png .

Comment: ...and if you were to `par.closest('#third').style.background = "yellow";` that would work..

Comment: If I understand well, his question is why `.closest()` doesn't return the element itself, as there is no matching `h2` parent

Comment: It returns the closest ancestor including itself that matches the selector. Itself is not an h2 and the h2 they expect is not an ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, this method returns the `closest ancestor`, depending of the `selector` you put in. In your case `h2` is not an ancestor of the `#my-id`, and it also can't return itself as they are not the same type, so the result is null. If you change `p#my-id` to `h2#my-id` it will work:

It is working in this example:

```js
var par = document.getElementById('my-id');

par.closest("h2").style.background = "yellow"; //returns itself
par.closest("#first").style.color = "red";   // change color of an ancestor
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="third">
      <h2 id="my-id">This is a paragraph</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I always thought of great uncles as ancestors. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that great uncles were ancestors. To access the heading, they could have used the `uncle selector`.

You use the `#closest` to find your grandfather and then use `previousElementSibling` to find his older brother.

```js
var par = document.getElementById('my-id');

par.closest("#second").previousElementSibling.style.background = "yellow";
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="third">    
      <p id="my-id">This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It must be noted that this does not work in IE and only works on Chrome in versions 41+. Chrome 41 was only released about a year ago.

Comment: "*I always thought that great uncles were ancestors*" well, that's the sort of confusion that can occur when terms are borrowed from other disciplines. But it does work if you consider the uncle to be by marriage, not ancestry (e.g. the husband of your mother's sister), so a sibling relationship, not direct hereditary. ;-)

Comment: Of course if you already know the id, just use `document.getElementById('second')` or `document.querySelector('#second')` since ids are unique to the document...